# Firefox keeps loading Twitch data when all Twitch tabs are closed

Tags: firefox, twitch

I just noticed that something was using up about 500KB/s of (down) internet connection in the background. After checking more in details, I found out that  this was used by Firefox, with a connection to 185.42.204.42:443, which then switched to 52.223.195.225:443. Both are Twitch IPs.

I don't have a single Twitch tab opened. I don't have a single stream running in any of my Firefox tabs. And yet, somehow, Firefox is loading 500KB/s of Twitch data in the background.

Is there a way to disable all background activity in Firefox? Something like: when I close a tab, terminate it fully and immediately, like I've always expected it to behave in the first place? I tried searching but all I found was someone with an AVG issue there https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/997796

Using Fx 64 on Windows 10 x64

Comment: Does this continue after restarting Firefox or after rebooting?

Comment: No, it only continues as long as the current instance of Firefox is running. If I quit Firefox and reload it (tab restore _is_ enabled), it's all fine then.

Comment: Check if this also happens in [Firefox Safe Mode](https://www.top-password.com/blog/5-simple-ways-to-start-firefox-in-safe-mode/). If this fixes it, then some add-on is the cause.

Comment: Well I'm failing to reproduce this today, even without the safe mode... I guess that must be why I hadn't noticed it before. Although I'm pretty sure it already happened in the past, as I had noticed unexplained data use by Firefox which I just never took the time to dig into until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the cause of this "problem": one of the sites I had in my always opened tabs was actually playing a Twitch stream silently in the background :x